# Using values in a pandas dataframe as column names for another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my first dataframe.

```
Date        0   1   2   3   
2003-01-31  CA  KY  ID  CO
2003-02-28  CA  KY  HI  CO 
2003-03-31  CA  KY  CO  HI
```

This is my second dataframe.

```
Date        CA  KY  ID  CO  HI                                            
2003-01-31   5   3   4   5   1 
2003-02-28   2   7   8   4   5  
2003-03-31   6   3   9   3   5
```

How do I get this dataframe to print as output?

```
Date         0   1   2   3                                                
2003-01-31   5   3   4   5
2003-02-28   2   7   5   4
2003-03-31   6   3   3   5
```

I am wondering if there is a way to use the whole dataframe as an index to another instead of having to loop through all the dates/columns.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community! Seems you have already read our guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), cause your question formatted pretty nice for a new user! Also, don't forget to upvote suggested answer and mark question as solved right after it. Or, if your question will be unanswered for a long time, but you will find a solution, don't be shy to share it with the community itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) here.

```
# If `Date` is not index.
# df1.set_index('Date')
#              0   1   2   3
# Date
# 2003-01-31  CA  KY  ID  CO
# 2003-02-28  CA  KY  HI  CO
# 2003-03-31  CA  KY  CO  HI

# df2.set_index('Date')
#             CA  KY  ID  CO  HI
# Date
# 2003-01-31   5   3   4   5   1
# 2003-02-28   2   7   8   4   5
# 2003-03-31   6   3   9   3   5

def f(x):
    return df2.lookup(x.index, x)

df1.apply(f)
# df1.apply(lambda x: df2.lookup(x.index, x)

            0  1  2  3
Date
2003-01-31  5  3  4  5
2003-02-28  2  7  5  4
2003-03-31  6  3  3  5
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print the values of dataframe df and the column name of dataframe df1.

```
print(df.rename(columns={i:j for i,j in zip(df.columns.tolist(),df1.columns.tolist())}))
```

if you want to make the changes permanent, add the parameter `inplace=TRUE`